# Visual Studio Code Node.js doesn't provide intellisense for npm module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, plaid

I am trying to use the Plaid module seen here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaid

And I have required the package into visual studio but there is no code complete for it. I installed the package with `npm install plaid --save` and everything works fine also the Plaid methods run fine but there is no auto complete in Visual Studio Code. A similar thing happened with Jquery but I fixed it by installing @types/jquery through npm. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked in the [npm](http://npmjs.com), there no `@types/plaid` for `plaid` so you can not take advantage of typescript with this module.